# Mongoose - Save doesnt work when am connecting to mongodb running in different server

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When am trying to save a document in a collection or find the list of collections in mongodb running remotely doesnt work but works when am connecting to mongo db locally. save doesnt show if it throwed an error or it was successful.
Your help is appreciated.
below is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbName = 'OST';
var connectionString = 'mongodb://vm-1b98-f53f.nam.nsroot.net:32017/OST?ssl=true&sslverifycertificate=false';

mongoose.connect(connectionString);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + connectionString);
var Region = require('./Region.js');
var r = new Region({ NodeID: 8687, RegionName: 'EMEA' });

r.save(function (err, regionObj) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error');
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log('saved successfully:', regionObj);
    }
});
mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (error, names) {
    if (error) {

        console.log(error);
    } else {
        names.map(function (cname) {
            console.log(cname.name);
        });
    }
});
});
process.on('SIGINT', function () {

mongoose.connection.close(function () {

    process.exit(0);

});

});
```

Comment: Are you seeing the `Mongoose default connection open` console.log line being output when you connect remotely?

Comment: Yes am able t see that line in the log

Comment: The same code works when i set the connection string to localhost mongodb running in my local box.. working on this for past 2 days..

Comment: Couple of thoughts: Is the mongo version the same at both ends? Is there any kind of user authentication enabled on the remote side, and is your user correctly permissioned?

Comment: do i need to check the mongo version in my local box and the remote server?

Comment: And there is no authentication enabled

Comment: My local box has MongoDB 3.0.3 and remote server has 2.6.8